# Fix face smoothing

Tags: shaders, faces, normals

I would like to know why it happens and how to fix this issue? I have a model imported from the `FBX` file. I want to add a face to this model. So, I select edges and press the `F` button. After this operation a smooth shading is broken in the faces that are next to a new created face. Please take a look at the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it's a flat surface it's probably best to stay with flat shading. You could try to reset your normals though.

Comment: @NascentSpace, How can I reset normals?

Comment: I don't think its broken it is how "Shade Smooth" should looks like. If you want "Shade Flat" as it appeared in the first screen Search for "Flat" or hit Ctrl+F (Cmd+F on Mac) and choose "Shade Flat".

Comment: Or you can try with your face selected Ctrl+E > Mark Sharp. BTW to reset normals press Alt+N > Reset Vectors.

Answer (score 3):

The shading artifacts are being caused by the n-gons surrounding the circle, as well as a lack of supporting geometry. As a quick fix, you could try selecting all the front faces that aren't part of the circle and giving them a slight inset:

Before inset (faces selected):
[image: Inset1]

After Inset:
[image: Inset2]

Comment: Could you explain how to make inset?

Comment: Select the front faces and press `I` (inset) and then enter a small value - I usually use something like 0.01.